# rsync + ssh in python subprocess gets error with spaces in directory name

Tags: python, ssh, rsync, quoting

When I run my Python application (that synchronizes a remote directory locally) I have a problem if the directory that contains my app has one or more spaces in its name.
Directory name appears in ssh options like "`-o UserKnownHostsFile=<path>`" and "`-i <path>`".
I try to double quote paths in my function that generates the command string, but nothing. I also try to replace spaces like this: `path.replace(' ', '\\ ')`, but it doesn't work.
Note that my code works with dirnames without spaces.
The error returned by ssh is "garbage at the end of line" (code 12)
The command line generated seems ok..

```
rsync -rztv --delete --stats --progress --timeout=900 --size-only --dry-run \
    -e 'ssh -o BatchMode=yes \
    -o UserKnownHostsFile="/cygdrive/C/Users/my.user/my\ app/.ssh/known_hosts" \
    -i "/cygdrive/C/Users/my.user/my\ app/.ssh/id_rsa"'
    user@host:/home/user/folder/ "/cygdrive/C/Users/my.user/my\ app/folder/"
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Does this command really work in your shell before calling it from Python? I'm unsure if you're either a) successfully accessing the known_hosts file b) successfully pre-established an ssh tunnel between both hosts

Comment: Yes, it works in Python when there is any space in path name.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried building your command as a list of arguments - I just had a similar problem passing a key file for the ssh connection:

```
command = [
  "rsync",
  "-rztv",
  "--delete",
  "--stats",
  "--progress",
  "--timeout=900",
  "--size-only",
  "--dry-run",
  "-e",
  "ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o UserKnownHostsFile='/cygdrive/C/Users/my.user/my\ app/.ssh/known_hosts' -i '/cygdrive/C/Users/my.user/my\ app/.ssh/id_rsa'",
  "user@host:/home/user/folder/",
  "/cygdrive/C/Users/my.user/my\ app/folder/"
]

sp = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output = sp.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: Using a list instead of a squashed string solves lots of quoting/escaping issues for me, beyond what is mentioned here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The returned data from the sub-command is including spaces as delimiters. Try updating the Internal Field Separator (IFS) list like:

```
# store a copy of the current IFS
SAVEIFS=$IFS;
# set IFS to be newline-only
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b");

# execute your command(s)
rsync -rztv --delete --stats --progress --timeout=900 --size-only --dry-run -e 'ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o UserKnownHostsFile="/cygdrive/C/Users/my.user/my\ app/.ssh/known_hosts" -i "/cygdrive/C/Users/my.user/my\ app/.ssh/id_rsa"' user@host:/home/user/folder/ "/cygdrive/C/Users/my.user/my\ app/folder/"

# put the original IFS back
IFS=$SAVEIFS;
```

I haven't tested using your command, though it has worked in all cases I've tried in the past.

Comment: Sorry but I am in Python (precisely I invoke the command inside a subprocess)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid escaping issues, use a raw string,

```
raw_string = r'''rsync -rztv --delete --stats --progress --timeout=900 --size-only --dry-run -e 'ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o UserKnownHostsFile="/cygdrive/C/Users/my.user/my app/.ssh/known_hosts" -i "/cygdrive/C/Users/my.user/my app/.ssh/id_rsa"' user@host:/home/user/folder/ "/cygdrive/C/Users/my.user/my app/folder/"'''

sp = subprocess.Popen(raw_string, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output = sp.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: I inserted my vars in your raw_string, like this:
 
    r'''-e 'ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o UserKnownHostsFile="''' + basePath + self.__knownHostsPathName + '''" -i "''' + basePath + self.__certPathName + '''"' ''' + self.__srcUser + '@' + self.__srcHost + ':' + srcPath + ''' "''' + basePath + dstPath + '''"'''

but I always obtain "command-line line 0: garbage at end of line".

Comment: Why would you do that..?  
You're defeating the purpose of using raw string facility - it auto escapes all you feed into it.

Comment: Try both,      

    raw_string = r'''/usr/bin/rsync -e /usr/bin/ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o UserKnownHostsFile="%s/%s" -i "%s/%s" %s@%s:%s "%s/%s"''' % (basePath, self.__knownHostsPathName, basePath, self.__certPathName, self.__srcUser, self.__srcHost, srcPath, basePath, dstPath)

Comment: raw_string = r'/usr/bin/rsync -e /usr/bin/ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o UserKnownHostsFile=%s/%s -i %s/%s %s@%s:%s "%s/%s"' % (basePath, self.__knownHostsPathName, basePath, self.__certPathName, self.__srcUser, self.__srcHost, srcPath, basePath, dstPath)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Joao, but: I keep obtaining "command-line line 0: garbage at end of line".

Comment: Ops, I forgot to say that my code is running both on linux, mac and windows (cwrsync): the problem is alive on windows